# Ssh and vnc server

Tags: ssh, vnc, kali, hotspot

I want to setup my pi 3 working with just  a power bank and my phone via mobile Hotspot. I know that ssh and vnc server are two ways to do it but I don't know how.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Network layer: decide whether to use your phone in tethering mode so it works as an access point, or configure the Pi to act as an access point. Unless you can connect both devices to an existing Wifi network, you'll need to put one device into access point (AP) mode.

   - phone as AP: connect your Pi to your phone AP using the usual Wifi procedure. You can do this from the Pixel desktop while your Pi is connected to an HDMI monitor, and ISB mouse and keyboard attached. Afterwards, it will remember this. Or you edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and add your phone's name (SSID) and key. See also https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md
   - Pi as AP: see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md for details how to configure your Pi, then connect your phone to the Pi's AP, like you connect to any other Wifi network.
2. Services

   - on the Pi use `sudo raspi-config` to enable SSH and/or VNC. I recommend enabling both, unless you want to use SSH only.
   - on your phone, get an SSH client app and/or the official VNC client app. On Android, I recommend JuiceSSH from my own personal experience. For VNC, use the official VNC client to avoid all kind of protocol issues with different VNC clients and servers.

Enjoy. I'm using such a setup on a regular basis to maintain a set of Pi Zero Ws, and even sometimes 3Bs. For me, SSH mostly sufficies, but from time to time I may need a GUI session, which is when VNC comes in handy.

Comment: Can u please suggest a simpler step guide because I'm new.

Comment: So, do you want to be the Pi the Wifi access point?

Comment: No I want my phone to be the access point

Comment: First enable ssh and vnc on the Pi using `raspi-config`. Then set up your phone for tethering, and connect your pi to it. You do it the same way as connecting to any other wifi network. Now the Pi's IP address that is shown on your phone. Finally, start the vnc client app on your phone and connect to the IP address you've seen in the list o of tethered devices on your phone.